# store address book contacts in an array in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I'm using below coding to get first name in string format but want to get this in an array  as it includes both address book contacts and facebook contact. So that I can retrieve them like array[0],array[1] and soon.So plz help me to get this done.

```
    ABAddressBookRef ab=ABAddressBookCreate();

    NSArray *arrTemp=(NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);

    NSMutableArray *arrContact=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       for (int i=0;i<[arrTemp count];i++) 
             {
    NSMutableDictionary *dicContact=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *str=(NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue([arrTemp objectAtIndex:i],             kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    @try
        {
    [dicContact setObject:str forKey:@"name"];
        }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
    [dicContact release];
    continue;
     }

    [dicContact release];

    NSLog(@"%@",str );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store Your addressBook all contacts in to NSMutableArray like bellow:-

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *thePeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
NSMutableArray* allPeoplesDicts = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id person in thePeople)
{
    ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
    NSMutableArray* phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
    {
        NSString *phone = [(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones,i) autorelease];
        [phones addObject:phone];
    }
    NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"Name",phones,@"PhoneNumbers",nil];
    [phones release];
    [allPeoplesDicts addObject:personDict];
    [personDict release];
}
```

i just Google it and i got this visit this similar questions:-

[how can I Add a ABRecordRef to a NSMutableArray in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071256/how-can-i-add-a-abrecordref-to-a-nsmutablearray-in-iphone)

[storing adressbook contacts into a nsdictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226027/storing-adressbook-contacts-into-a-nsdictionary)

Comment: Thanks Nitin for the answer.

Comment: Ya I have tick right and for upvoting it is saying reputation must be atleast 15

Comment: I have taken the name in to array and it giving output in console by doing nslog as 2013-01-12 16:15:58.955 Birthday_Reminder[1757:c07] (
    "Salil Pachori"
) and by printing that array into nslog(@"%@",array[1]) it is showing error so how can I do that so it comes in array[1],array[2] form